# Undefined method of global variable with Node.js in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, global, webstorm

For complicated reasons, I have some Node.js code like this:

(util.js)

```
global.redis= require('redis').createClient(...);
```

(some other file.js)

```
const Util= require('./util.js');
global.redis.rpush(...);
```

In WebStorm 8, when I inspect the code it will recognize global.redis but will error saying unresolved function or method rpush.
redis is listed in the Node.js and NPM settings in WebStorm and I have Node.js globals enabled.

The code runs as expected though.
Has anyone run into this?

Comment: webstorm tries its best to figure out the methods available on your objects. javascript is a dynamic language and its hard to do this. sometimes it fails.

Comment: some known issues that may be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12286, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11524